# QlikView: Adjust Bubble Size

Tags: qlikview

How can I make all the bubbles in a QlikView Bubble Chart larger? The default bubbles are too small, and do not display the data in an appealing manner.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a third expression will affect the bubble size.

Have a look at the properties of this chart to see what affects what

[image]

The first Dimension creates the bubbles, 1 bubble per dimension entry.

The second Dimension assigns the colours to bubbles ie 1 colour per group otherwise you would get 1 colour per bubble.

[image]

The first Expression creates the X-Axis values.

The second Expression creates the Y-Axis values.

And the third Expression sizes the bubbles.

[image]

Comment: In Presentation tab there is 'Max Bubble Size' setting. That is what I was looking for. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

In Presentation tab there is 'Max Bubble Size' setting. That is what I was looking for.